# Main file don't sees incuded header in stdafx.h

Tags: c++, precompiled-headers

Hey I have strange problem... 
When I'm adding a class into my project in VS 2015 
Im including new class into stdafx.h, and stdafx I including to file with main function. When I compiling a program, VS throws Error:

I show it on the code:
stdafx.h

```
#pragma once
#include  <time.h>

#include <map>
#include "targetver.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include "FreeImage.h"

#include "vec3.h"
#include "vec2.h"
#include "vec4.h"

#include "TextureManager.h"
#include "SceneObject.h"
#include "Obj3d.h"
#include "Door.h"
#include "Collider.h"
#include "TrashGen.h"

#include "Player.h"
#include "Scene.h"
```

Door.h:

```
class Door
{
public:
Door();
~Door();

int key;
};
```

Door.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Door.h"


Door::Door()
{
   key = 10;
} 


Door::~Door()
{
}
```

When i add in main function:

in this file I included stdafx.h

Door *dor;

i have an error:

Error   C2065   'dor': undeclared identifier    IROBOTGAME
Error   C2065   'Door': undeclared identifier   IROBOTGAME

Comment: https://github.com/serkaz97/IROBOTGAME repository with project

Comment: How's your main code?

Comment: It's means file with main function, I added link to repository

Comment: Problem solved btw

Comment: Can you explain how it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Visual C++ looses its way with the precompiled headers, depending on the sequence of your edits.
Simply do a full 'Rebuild', that might fix it.